# : Undefined property: stdClass::$usd in

Tags: php

Okay I am using a framework so I can pull database rows like: $username->thenthenameoftherow
But the row I want it to bet a variable because the variable is defined via a post method, I run that variable through an explode to get the first part, the text before the _
Yet when I run:  and get currency like:

```
    $coin = $_POST['coin'];
    //currency they want to user
    $currency = explode('_', $coin);

    $username->$currency[1]
```

I can't set a hardcoded row for that, it has to be a userdefined viariable
I get the error:

Notice: `Undefined property: stdClass::$usd in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\application\controllers\dashboard.php on line 193`

Using mini mvc framework

Okay, for an exampple the post to set the $coin is BTC_USD I then explode it to remove the _ and get the 2nd part of the string which is USD I then want to get the USD table from my database by running the user query but I get that error.

Comment: what is on line 193?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically:

```
$_tmp = $username->$currency;
$result = $_tmp[1];
```

Did you mean:

```
$_tmp = $currency[1];
$result = $username->$_tmp;
```

? Because if so, you want:

```
$result = $username->{$currency[1]};
```

Comment: Still get the same error: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$usd

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
$username->currency[1]
```

without $ before currency

Comment: This IS an answer.  It is pointing out a potential syntax error in the code.